# single-tenant with rapid personalization on Ruby on rails, Saas application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multi-tenant, saas, infrastructure

As I am a bit new to infrastructure, I hope you can give me a little heads-up !

I've been creating a new app for a client of mine, that I want to replicate to other client. I want to offer the possibility for my client to add new feature if they want to.

I came up with this interogation: "If I improve some code to a client apps, how can I also improve other clients app quickly",

The conclusion I came with: Create a modular rails app in order to maintain easy update of code, and offer scalable personalization.

current infrastructure: multiple separate heroku app,
scaling infrastructure: amazon EC2 with multiple DB (usefull info: no more than 100 differents users)

Does anyone had the same problem to manage ?

Thanks for you help !

Jonathan.

Comment: This is really way too broad for Stack Overflow to answer. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: You have a SaaS Problem and is widely being used, probably you could have gotten an answer by skimming through the questions tagged here in the `multi-tenant` category. Present your problem here for the community to help you.